# Please explain this Map key-type constraint recipe to me

Tags: ocaml

I am new to OCaml and such languages.

I have been experimenting with `Map` and ended up with:

```ml
type thing = ThingA | ThingB

module ThingMap = Map.Make(String)

let things = [
    ("a", ThingA);
    ("b", ThingB)
  ] |> List.to_seq
    |> ThingMap.of_seq
```

So far so good, I've got a map of strings to things.

Then I was reading that `Map.Make(String)` only enforces the type of the keys, the values could be any type.

I found this recipe for enforcing that values should be of `thing` type:

```ml
let m: thing ThingMap.t ref = ref ThingMap.empty
```

The recipe seems useful but I don't understand how it works.

Three questions:

1. what does `m` represent? it has type `type thing ThingMap.t ref` but that doesn't mean much to me... is it useful for anything? can I just rename it to `_`?
2. does declaring this in a module enforce the constraint for all instances of `ThingMap` in any module? (is "instances" the right word?)
3. what's up with the `ref` and `empty`? how does this work?

### Update

After experimenting a bit more with benefit of @Jeffrey Scofield's helpful answer I can see that this recipe is not needed in my case (initialising an immutable Map from a list of key-value pairs).

First I observe that I get a type error if subsequent elements of the list do not have same type as the first element:

```ml
let things = [
    ("a", ThingA);
    ("b", 123)
  ] |> List.to_seq
    |> ThingMap.of_seq
```

```
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         thing
```

Cool, but that's not enough because if the "wrong" element is in the first position I get the "wrong" type error for the constraint I intended:

```ml
let things = [
    ("a", 123);
    ("b", ThingB)
  ] |> List.to_seq
    |> ThingMap.of_seq
```

```
Error: This expression has type thing but an expression was expected of type
         int
```

I can fix this by understanding that the part after the colon in `let m: thing ThingMap.t ...` is a type signature, so I can get the result I want by adding a signature to `things`:

```ml
let things: thing ThingMap.t = [
    ("a", 123);
    ("b", ThingB)
  ] |> List.to_seq
    |> ThingMap.of_seq
```

```
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         thing
```

Here the first item has wrong type, but I get the type error I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m` is a global variable (a name) that is declared by the `let`. This is not a sweeping declaration that all values of type `ThingMap` contain values of type `thing`. It's just a declaration of one such map (accessed through a reference). You could later use `ThingMap.t` with values of any type.

```
# let m : thing ThingMap.t ref = ref ThingMap.empty;;
val m : thing ThingMap.t ref = {contents = <abstr>}
# let n : int ThingMap.t ref = ref ThingMap.empty;;
val n : int ThingMap.t ref = {contents = <abstr>}
```

Here I declared a value `m`, a reference to a map from strings to things. Then I declared a value `n`, a reference to a map from strings to ints.

The left side of `let` is a pattern. You can certainly use `_` for this pattern but then you would have no name by which to refer to your map.

This declaration doesn't enforce any constraints on anything except the specific variable `m`.

If you don't know what references are, you should learn about them. In essence a reference is a mutable cell that always contains a value of one type, but it can be modified to contain different values of the type. (On the other hand, it's good when starting with OCaml to try to code without using references.)

`ThingMap.empty` is a map with no keys (and hence no values).

If you really want to control the values used in `ThingMap`, you can define it in a module that specifies types for the functions that access the map. Once you've defined `ThingMap.t` as a visible type, there's no way to change its meaning to make it more restricted.

If you just want a handy name for the type of maps from strings to things, you can give it a name:

```
type thingmap = thing ThingMap.t
```

**Update**

Here is a previous SO discussion of OCaml (immutable) variable bindings and references:

[What is the difference between let-bindings and references in OCaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31307788/what-is-the-difference-between-let-bindings-and-references-in-ocaml/31308222?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C26.2628#31308222)

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. Am I right to think of `m` in this example as an "instance"? I understood that Maps are immutable. Does the `ref` get around that and mean I could mutate `m` by adding keys to it?  That would explain why this recipe is useful, if it was restricting values type of an immutable empty Map that would not be very useful.

Comment: The problem with "instance" is that it has a technical OO meaning. This part of OCaml isn't object oriented, so it's better to think of `m` as a reference to a value of type `thing ThingMap.t`. You can mutate `m`, yes. You can set it to different values, which is the point of using a reference. Note that it's just `m` that changes. The maps are immutable, they don't change. Just `m` changes.

Comment: If the maps are still immutable and we're just changing which one `m` points to, how is `let m: thing ThingMap.t ref = ref ThingMap.empty;;`  different from `let m: thing ThingMap.t = ThingMap.empty;;` ?

Comment: If you don't declare `m` as a reference it is immutable. You can't change the `m` in this new declaration. It will always be the empty map. OCaml "variables" are immutable. Calling them variables is a bit of a misnomer but is the historical practice in lambda calculus.

Comment: But I can subsequently `let m: thing ThingMap.t = ThingMap.of_seq (List.to_seq [("a", ThingA)]);;` and `m` will then be a map with one binding in it. I guess what you are saying is that without `ref` this is now a "different" `m`? Which is a semantic that may have consequences in my program. Whereas doing the same with a `ref` would assign a new value _to the original `m`_ ?

Comment: Yes the second `m` is a different `m`. Any uses of the previous `m` (in function definitions say) will not change their value, for example. This is getting too complicated for this "comment" area. A tutorial on OCaml might be informative.